# Please try to ask more questions

Tags: discussion, questions

We have a rapidly decreasing quantity of questions. Our average is 12.5 questions per day and we have only had 4 questions in the past 24 hours. Note that asking poor quality questions that are just gaming the QPD system is not what I am asking. Make sure they are high quality and high volume (quality over volume) to help us advance from private beta.

Comment: We just finished asking all the easy questions, not it's time for real questions. Quality over quanitty

Comment: I said that literally exactly @mousetail

Comment: you've asked 2, and your last one was over a week ago. you're talking to yourself too, right?

Comment: I don’t have any high quality questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's natural for the rate of questions being posted each day to stagnate during the private beta. People run out of ideas of what to post, and the private beta period by definition doesn't really attract new people who can fill in the posting gap. There's not a real need to ask more questions as long as we still have a few trickling in each day or two.

Answer (score 4):

## As long as we're above 10/day we're doing great

We get no special golden star for having a ridiculously high questions/day stat. As long as we're above 10 it's green: we're doing great. A slower asking rate gives us more time to answer and discuss the questions that do get posted, which helps our other stats, and the asking experience overall.

If our questions/day does start to slip significantly below 10 it might be worth a push to get people back to the site, but for now, especially given that it's going to be right at the end of the school year for a lot of people, I don't think we have anything to be concerned about.

Comment: I don't think "school year" matters for the professionals we actually care about

Comment: Also most beta sites get around 5/day when they graduate so even if we go below it's not a huge issue

Comment: @mousetail We "actually care about" every one of our users. (and many of the professionals will be in academia).

Comment: I think that the school year isnt the main reason. Also, that 10 QPD is because we started with 75 QPD, @mousetail

Comment: We are now at 7.3 @RydwolfPrograms